# retain count of objects in AutoReleasePool

Tags: objective-c, nsautoreleasepool

I have a situation where I need to add each new object in auto release pool. This operation will be called some 60 times a second. In doing so retain count of the object will keep on incrementing. In the sense, autoreleasepool contents are not releasing. But when some events(mouse, keyboard) are performed, autoreleasepool releases its content objects.
Does anybody know the reason behind this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, autoreleasepool called only when after your event cycle end. In main run loop managing and triggers events which is one after other event. When event not in run loop then its ideal. So autorelease calling when event cycle end in existing main run loop pool. So your autoreleased called when you trigger some event (like mouse, keyboard), it means that your main runloop end current event cycle and start new event cycle for mouse and keyboard and just before starting new event cycle it run autorelease pool to clearing all objects in pool.

Go through [RunLoopManagement doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html) and [CreatingThreads](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html)